# How to UPDATE SELECT with multiple joins in MySQL 5.x

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a table with classifieds, adding article IDs to each reacord if a matching article is existent. Defined by matching ref_id, dial_ids.

Now I am somehow stuck with the UPDATE SELECT query.

[SQL Fiddle with Structure](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5ab9e/1)

Structure table **classifieds**:

```
ID, article_id
```

Structure table **articles**:

```
article_id, dial_id, ref_id
```

Structure table **classifieds_attr**:

```
attr_group_id, cl_id, value
```

The following query gives me the matching classified_ids:

```
-- get all classified ids where we have matching articles
SELECT
a.article_id,
ca_d.cl_id,
a.dial_id,
a.ref_id
FROM 
    `articles` a
-- get classified_ids where ref_id match the article
INNER JOIN classifieds_attr ca_r ON ca_r.attr_group_id = 8 AND ca_r.value = a.ref_id
-- filter down for matching dial
INNER JOIN classifieds_attr ca_d ON ca_r.cl_id = ca_d.cl_id AND ca_d.attr_group_id = 9 AND ca_d.value = a.dial_id
```

Altering the SQL in order to update the table classifieds with matching records:

```
-- update classified table and insert article_id if matching article available
UPDATE c, a
SET 
    c.article_id = ca_d.cl_id,
    c.date_edited = ca.date_edited
FROM 
    classifieds c,
    articles a
-- get classified_ids where ref_id match the article
INNER JOIN classifieds_attr ca_r ON ca_r.attr_group_id = 8 AND ca_r.value = a.ref_id
-- filter down for matching dial
INNER JOIN classifieds_attr ca_d ON ca_r.cl_id = ca_d.cl_id AND ca_d.attr_group_id = 9 AND ca_d.value = a.dial_id
```

The syntax is somehow wrong. How can the SQL Query be altered to update the classifieds toable with coresponding article_ids?

Comment: I don't see any restriction on the join between `classifieds` and `articles`.  It appears to be a cross join, and I doubt this is what you really want.  You might want to add table definitions and sample data for best results here.

Comment: Please use sqlfiddle for adding sample data and table structure in it and someone will surely help you !

Comment: MySQL does not use `FROM` in `UPDATE` queries unless in a subquery.

Comment: @Parfait OK, I tried before with UPDATE tablename SELECT... but this did not work either. I added the structure and query to sqlfiddle. Can somebody point me to the right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have a `FROM` clause for `UPDATE`.  I don't see how `classified`s is connects to the other tables, so fill in the `JOIN` condition.  The query would look like:

```
UPDATE articles a JOIN
       classifieds_attr ca_r
       ON ca_r.attr_group_id = 8 AND ca_r.value = a.ref_id JOIN
       classifieds_attr ca_d
       ON ca_r.cl_id = ca_d.cl_id AND ca_d.attr_group_id = 9 AND ca_d.value = a.dial_idclassifieds c JOIN
       classifieds c
       ON c.? = ?  -- whatever the right JOIN condition is
    SET c.article_id = ca_d.cl_id,
        c.date_edited = ca.date_edited
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked with a bit alteration: -- update classified table and insert article_id if matching article available
UPDATE articles a 
-- get classified_ids where ref_id match the article
JOIN classifieds_attr ca_r
       ON ca_r.attr_group_id = 8 AND ca_r.value = a.ref_id 
-- filter down for matching dial
JOIN classifieds_attr ca_d
       ON ca_r.cl_id = ca_d.cl_id AND ca_d.attr_group_id = 9 AND ca_d.value = a.dial_id
-- join the cl table with articles
JOIN classifieds c
       ON c.ID = ca_d.cl_id  
SET 
 c.article_id = a.article_id,
    c.date_edited = c.date_edited